# ¿Se puede borrar una palabra en específico de un archivo .txt a través de Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, archivo, txt, texto

Estoy creando un sencillo programa en el que creo un archivo .txt y escribo en él los invitados que han venido. Tras esto lo cierro. Aquí está (aún estoy aprendiendo, así que agradecería cualquier sugerencia):

```
x=0
import time
ts = time.time()
tc = time.ctime(ts)
ts = ts + 86400  # hasta aquí sólo para decir la hora
archivo = open ("listadeinvitad@s.txt", "a+")
archivo.write('Los invitados/as que vinieron el ')
archivo.write(tc)
archivo.write(' son: ')
while x != 'Stop':
    x = input('Escribe el nombre de la persona (escribe "Stop" para finalizar) ')
    archivo.write(x)
    archivo.write(', ')
archivo.write('\n')
archivo.close()
print('Lista de invitados guardada en "listadeinvitad@s.txt"')
```

Pero me encontré con el problema de que al final del archivo salía: "alguien, alguien, Stop, ". Para solucionar lo del ",Stop, ", lo único que se me ocurrió que podía hacer era añadir algún tipo de "eliminador de texto", algo que tendría este aspecto:

```
while x != 'Stop':
    x = input('Escribe el nombre de la persona (escribe "Stop" para finalizar) ')
    archivo.write(x)
    archivo.write(', ')
    archivo.erase(5)  #Esto haría que se borrasen 5 caracteres hacia atrás desde la posición del puntero
archivo.close()
```

Sin embargo, quisiera saber si eso existe realmente, o en caso de que no, si hay algún modo sencillo de conseguir que no aparezca el último ", Stop, "

Comment: La verdadera solución es la que propone Candid Moe (evitar cometer el error en primer lugar), pero respondiendo a tu pregunta original: no, python no tiene nada similar, inevitablemente tendrías que reescribir todo el fichero para lograr eso. Pero insisto, es mejor no cometer el error que cometerlo y deshacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mejor que andar corrigiendo errores es no cometerlos en primer lugar; hay mejores maneras de hacer las cosas.

El patrón estándar para estos casos es usar un ciclo infinito `while True:` y escapar de él con `break` cuando se cumpla la condición de fin:

```
while True:
    x = input('Escribe el nombre de la persona (escribe "Stop" para finalizar) ')
    if x == 'Stop':
        break
    #  Procesar el ingreso del usuario.
```

También tienes otra complicación típica, que es agregar algo (una coma), pero sólo entre los items: no al final, no si solo hay uno.

El patrón es crear un booleano que me diga si ya grabe un nombre antes, y luego grabar la coma o no según corresponda.

La solución completa:

```
primero = True
while True:
    x = input('Escribe el nombre de la persona (escribe "Stop" para finalizar) ')
    if x == 'Stop':
        break
    if primero:
        archivo.write(x)
        primero = False
    else:
        archivo.write(f", {x}")
```